# Why is the body background image covering the HTML tag background?

Tags: css

I have two images one is attached to the HTML(background) tag and is positioned bottom, left and repeat X.
I have another background image attached to the body tag, that is positioned top left and also repeat X.

I noticed the Body is covering the html image. I am not sure if this is possible and I have tried searching but no solution.

Is there a way to make the body image stay under the html image?

This way the html (image attached to the background) is on top of the body (background) image?

```
html {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(../graphics/main-background-image-x.png);
}

body {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url(../graphics/sub-background-image-x.png);
}
```

Comment: ^ What he said.  You can use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to post example code so that people can see your issue.  In response to your problem, could you not just swap the images around...?

Comment: Added the code, I did not add the code because this is as straight as an arrow. :) Anyway, swapping the code does not help because the idea is to make the image tile to cover the entire browser window. For some reason when you minimized the window, the body image stop repeating pass the initial window size. Putting the image on the html, enabled it to cover the window regardless of resizing.

Answer (score 1):

The site [here](http://www.lakelandradiology.com/) achieved what I believe you are looking for by adding `height: 100%;` to both the body and html tags.

```
html{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url(../graphics/main-background-image-x.png);
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    background-image: url(../graphics/sub-background-image-x.png);
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Great!, adding html,body{ height: 100%;} , fixed this issue on my website thx :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want:

```
html
{
    background:Transparent url(../graphics/sub-background-image-x.png) repeat-x left top;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

body
{
    background:Transparent url(../graphics/main-background-image-x.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html {
    background: url(../graphics/main-background-image-x.png) repeat-x left bottom transparent;
}

body {
    background: url(../graphics/sub-background-image-x.png) repeat-x left top transparent;
}
```